# Combine MERGE in FOREACH with transaction in cypher script

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-shell

I am trying to make a cypher script file for usage in *cypher-shell*.

#### Purpose

The result should be a bunch of nodes named 'Constant'. For some I just use a map as property, for others I additionally try to *set* a `createdAt` property [dynamically](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create). All this should happen in a [FOREACH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22338998/2092322), wrapped in a [transaction](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-transactions).

#### For now it looks like this

```
:begin
WITH [
        {type: 'singleHouse', debug: true},
        {type: 'apartmentHouse', debug: true }
    ] AS constantHouseholdTypes
    FOREACH (constantHouseholdType in constantHouseholdTypes | CREATE (n:Constant:HouseholdType) SET n=constantHouseholdType);
:commit

:begin
WITH [
        {name: 'unit:area:squareMeter', domain: 'area', scaling: false, debug: true}
    ] as units
    FOREACH (unit in units | CREATE (u:Constant:Unit) SET u=unit, u.createdAt = timestamp())
:commit
```

### Edit: No error anymore

I do not see the error anymore for any reason.

Versions:
Bolt: 4.2
Neo4J 4.2.3

#### But I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid input ':': expected 
  <EOF>
  "RETURN"
  "CREATE"
  "DELETE"
  "SET"
  "REMOVE"
  "DETACH"
  "MATCH"
  "WITH"
  "UNWIND"
  "USE"
  "CALL"
  "LOAD"
  "FROM"
  "FOREACH"
  "MERGE"
  "OPTIONAL"
  "UNION" (line 7, column 1 (offset: 207))
":commit"
 ^
```

And no node has been added (which is exactly what is supposed to happen for an error in a transaction):

```
MATCH (c:Constant) RETURN c;
+---+
| c |
+---+
+---+

0 rows available after 5 ms, consumed after another 2 ms
```

Any idea, what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you run this using cypher-shell?

Comment: @Luanne I am connecting to the DB in `cypher-shell` and then I type `:source /path/to/cypher-scripts/test.cypher`.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? I tried your script and it works on 4.1

Comment: @Luanne `neo4j --version` -> `neo4j 4.2.3`. It runs on an Ubuntu 20 system and I don't know of any other problem, yet.

Comment: @Luanne wow, I just tried it again and this time it also worked for me. I have no clue what the problem could have been.